# !We need to go deeper! Items in mongoDB won't delete

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I created a simple REST 'todo-List' and everything works fine except deleting items from my mongoDB.

When I delete an item via my main.js file I get a 200 response for my 'DELETE' method. However the item is not deleted from mongoDB and thus still displays in my list.

I used the deleteOne() method instead remove() since the latter is deprecated according to the message I got, but that won't turn the tide.

can anyone help here.

The code in my app.js accessing the db which should delete the item.

```
let express = require('express');
let app = express();
let bodyParser = require('body-parser');
let mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://Daniel:xxxxxx@clusterpetertester-h0t6v.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {useUnifiedTopology: true, useNewUrlParser: true, useCreateIndex: true });

let taskSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
  item: String
})

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('./'))


let Task = mongoose.model("Tasks", taskSchema);

app.get('/todoparents', function(req, res) {
  Task.find({}, function(err, item) {
    if (err) {
    } else {
      res.render('todoparents', {item : item})
    }
  });
});

//submit button route
app.post('/newTask', function(req, res) {
  console.log(' item submitted! ');
  let newItem = new Task({
    item: req.body.input
  })
  Task.create(newItem, function (err, Task) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else {
      console.log("Inserted Item : " + newItem)
    }
  })
  res.redirect('todoparents');
});

app.delete('/todoparents/:item', function (req, res) {
  //delete the requested item form mongodb
  Task.find({item: req.params.item.replace(/\-/g,"")}).deleteOne(function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    res.json(data)
    console.log(data)
  });
});


let port = 3333;
app.listen(port);
console.log('The server is up on port #', port);
```

Here is my html in my todoparents.ejs

```
<div class="container">

          <h1>Time to burden the children</h1>

          <ul id="taskList">
              <% for(var i=0; i < item.length; i++) { %>
                <li class="task-item<%=[i] %>"> 
                  <span class="task-info"> <%= item[i].item %> </span>
                  <span class="delete">Delete</span> 
                </li>
             <% } %>
          </ul>     

        </div>
```

The code in main.js getting correct 'span' on click from my todoparents.ejs

```
//gets the first span in an li and returns the textcontent
let taskList_Ul = document.getElementById('taskList');
taskList_Ul.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  let clickedElement = e.target;
  let content_clicked_Sibling = clickedElement.previousElementSibling.textContent;

  //the spaces are replaced with not spaces
  let item = content_clicked_Sibling.replace(/ /g, "");

// getting the url and attaching the item which was targeted
  fetch('/todoparents/' + item, {
  method: 'DELETE',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}).then(response => response.json()
    .then(data => {
      return data;
    })
  );
});
```

Here is the data i got from the console.log(data) in app.js. It seems nothing is deleted since at the end we have deletedCount: 0

```
{ n: 0,
  opTime:
   { ts:
      Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1572802291 },
     t: 5 },
  electionId: 7fffffff0000000000000005,
  ok: 1,
  operationTime:
   Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1572802291 },
  '$clusterTime':
   { clusterTime:
      Timestamp { _bsontype: 'Timestamp', low_: 1, high_: 1572802291 },
     signature: { hash: [Binary], keyId: [Long] } },
  deletedCount: 0 }
```

[image: Mongodb_Collection]

The UX of the app (very simple)
[image: UX of app]

image of console after trying to delete an item.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.find()` you should do this:

```
Task.deleteOne({item: req.params.item.replace(/\-/g,"")}, function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  res.json(data)
  console.log(data)
});
```

Comment: I tried using this,  but in this case I don't even get a 200 response. I.e. no status response at all. :=( Actually, the app crashes.

Comment: If it helps I was following a tutorial here.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yox93sB2PyQ&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gcy9lrvMJ75z9maRw4byYp&index=37
However, the dude was using an ajax request in his front end js

Comment: What does `req.params.item` contains? An array or what?

Comment: just a string of an item i had previously added. I should be the same as in the span I got in the main.js file.
so - string of an item would be: 

{"_id":{"$oid":"5dbee9286474e92080db79cd"},
"item":"eat a meal","__v":{"$numberInt":"0"}}
It's just the item in the object in the MongoDB
Does that make sense?

Comment: I can add the entire app.js file, it might help. Please see app.js above. The app.delete which was there previously is now at the end of that code.

Comment: console.log(req.params.item) contains the item e.g. eatfruits or eatameal!

Comment: If in you db you have an item like this `eat-fruit` then it won't be deleted because you are removing the `-` before running the query using regex.

Comment: that would make sense, but in the database there are no '-' there are only empty spaces so 'eat fruits' becomes 'eatfruits' after the replace method.

I also could go like this "item: req.params.item.replace(" ","")" and this would give me the same result.

Comment: @Dan would you give a screenshot of your db collection?

Comment: sure thing, incoming!

Comment: Remove `let item = content_clicked_Sibling.replace(/ /g, "");` this line and try again please.

Comment: This would throw an 'undefined' in the fetch method since the url depends on the item. It is appended i.e. : '' fetch('/todoparents/' + item, ''

Comment: Here is the thing, you are trying do delete `getfruits` but your db doesn't have it. Your database has `get fruits`. These are two different things. You can use `_id` instead of `item` in your client side javascript. And delete by id `Task.deleteOne({_id: req.params.item})`.

Comment: I need to call it a day, this is going to drive me nuts otherwise, if I come up with a solution I will keep you posted, and thank you for your efforts so far.

Answer (score 0):

What is the format of the primary key _id field you are using? Is it the standard `ObjectId`? If so, you may need to cast the value you are passing as the _id field to the delete call into an `ObjectId` before deleting. Otherwise, you are actually sending a string value, which is not found in the _id column, and the delete call deletes zero records.

Comment: I am not sure, but do I need to send a format for the primary key_id if I am not deleting for ID? I am trying to access the item in the DB which has the specified string I got from the html document.